# R - Pass a function of colorQuantile() to a leaflet()'s fillColor inside an ifelse()

Tags: r, leaflet

Consider the following reproducible example:

```
library(RCurl)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
download.file("https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_parks_and_protected_lands.zip",
              destfile = "test.zip")
unzip("test.zip")
test <- readOGR(dsn = "ne_10m_parks_and_protected_lands_area.shp")

min <- min(strtoi(test@data$scalerank))
max <- max(strtoi(test@data$scalerank))
pal <- colorQuantile(colorRamp(c("#000000", "#FFFFFF")), domain = min:max)

leaflet(test) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(weight = 2,
              fillColor =
                ifelse("whatever" != "whatever",
                       "#FFFF00",
                       ~pal(strtoi(test@data$scalerank))))
```

You will notice that there is an error:

```
Error in rep(no, length.out = len) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'
```

This is due to the fact that we try to use the tilde (~) operator inside an `ifelse()` statement, before the `pal()` function call. For my use case, I need to plot different palettes based on a condition. If I remove the tilde, everything appears in the same color. And if I remove the `ifelse()` statement everything works as expected:

```
library(RCurl)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
download.file("https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_parks_and_protected_lands.zip",
              destfile = "test.zip")
unzip("test.zip")
test <- readOGR(dsn = "ne_10m_parks_and_protected_lands_area.shp")

min <- min(strtoi(test@data$scalerank))
max <- max(strtoi(test@data$scalerank))
pal <- colorQuantile(colorRamp(c("#FFFFFF", "#000000")), domain = min:max)

leaflet(test) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(weight = 2,
              fillColor = ~pal(strtoi(test@data$scalerank)))
```

Apologies if the resulting map does not have many differences between colors, but if you check it thoroughly you can see it is working correctly.

EDIT: I need the `ìfelse()` as a part of a refactor because previously, there were enormous functions repeated in if/else statements. Compressing the code this way will improve reusability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `~`, it is that you misused `ifelse`. `ifelse` does return an object the size of your bollean test. Here:

```
ifelse("whatever" != "whatever",
       "#FFFF00",
       pal(strtoi(test@data$scalerank)))
```

gives

```
 "#FF0000"
```

instead of the whole `pal`:

```
pal(strtoi(test@data$scalerank))
 [1] "#FF0000" "#7F7F00" "#00FF00" "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000"
[11] "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#BF3F00" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#7F7F00"
[21] "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#7F7F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#7F7F00"
[31] "#FF0000" "#7F7F00" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#BF3F00"
[41] "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#BF3F00" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#FF0000"
[51] "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#7F7F00" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#BF3F00" "#FF0000" "#FF0000"
[61] "#FF0000"
```

because your test is of length 1:

```
> "whatever" != "whatever"
[1] FALSE
```

A test of length 2 will gives back vectors of length 2, etc:

```
ifelse(!c("whatever","whatever") %in% "whatever",
        "#FFFF00",
        pal(strtoi(test@data$scalerank)))

[1] "#FF0000" "#7F7F00"
```

So or you use a test of the size of your outputs, or you should use an simple `if` statement:

```
leaflet(test) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(weight = 2,
              fillColor = ~   if("whatever" != "whatever"){
                "#FFFF00"}else{
                  pal(strtoi(test@data$scalerank))
              })
```

Comment: It has the same effect as deleting the tilde. The map, as a result, is monochrome. So I would need another approach. Nevertheless, thank you very much, as I did not try it in this way.
PS. If you have to check the color, zoom in into the "Bears Ears National Monument". You will perceive a slightly different color between the two polygons if you delete the `ìfelse()`

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a lot of `ifelse()` inside of the `leaflet()` function and when I replaced them to `if()` and `else()`'s everything started working again. Although the key was your answer. Thank you!